# Google Maps API v3, validation of html form in info-window with dynamic resize

Tags: css, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I've got an HTML form in a Google Maps info window that uses the jQuery validation plugin.  When it displays error messages (I've moved them under the form input) the div with the form overflows the info window.

I've read responses to similar questions, but I haven't gotten a fix with any of those solutions.

HTML form:

```
<div id="formDiv">
  <form action="addRow.php" method="post"id="htmlForm">
     <fieldset>
        <p id="contactP">
          <label for="contact">Email:</label>
          <input type="text" name="contact" id="contact"/> <br/>
        </p>
        <p id="dateP">
          <label for="datepicker">Date:</label>
          <input type="text" name="date" id="datepicker"/> <br/>
        </p>
        <p id="latP">
          <label for="lat">Latitude:</label>
          <input type="text" name="lat" id="lat" class="location"/> <br/>'+
        </p>
        <p id="lngP">
          <label for="lng">Longitude:</label>
          <input type="text" name="lng" id="lng" class="location"/> <br/>
        </p>
        <p id="descP">
          <label for="desc" id="dos">Description of Sighting:</label> <br/>
          <textarea name="desc" id="desc"></textarea><br/>
        </p>

          <input type="submit" class="button" id="submitBtn" value="Post Sighting!" onclick="postSighting();"/>'+
      <p class="clear"></p>'+
     </fieldset></form></div>
```

;

jQuery:

```
$('#htmlForm').validate({
    rules: {
        contact: {required:true, email:true},
        date: {required:true},
        lat: {required:true},
        lng: {required:true},
        desc: {required:true},
    },
    messages: {
        desc: 'Please be descriptive!'
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        error.appendTo($('#' + element.attr('id') + 'P'));
        if (element.attr('id') == 'desc') {
            error.css({
                text_align: 'center',
                color: 'red',
                padding: 45,
            });
        } else {
            error.css({
                color: 'red',
                padding: 10,
                margin:0,
            })};
    }
});
```

Comment: Why is this tagged google-maps-api-3?

Comment: That's the whole point -- it's an HTML form inside of a google maps info-window.  The info-window doesn't re-size to accommodate the div that contains the inserted error messages.

Comment: A link to live code would be very valuable.  None of your code has anything to do with the Maps API.  You likely won't get an answer unless you provide a link to code and provide a bit more detail.

Comment: JsFiddle doesn't seem to run the validate code -- that portion runs correctly on my end (ie9 & chrome).
http://jsfiddle.net/rhewitt/gqa6k/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: you must ensure that the new content will always fit into the infoWindow(an infoWindow can't be larger than the map)

The issue:  when the validation-plugin modifies the contents, the content_changed-event of the infoWindow will not fire(but this is required for resizing the infoWindow)

It will not be sufficient to trigger the content_changed-event of the infoWindow, this will reset the contents to the current content-property of the infoWindow(which didn't change when your plugin modifies the content)

So you must set the content after the plugin modified the markup by setting the content to the current subTree inside the infoWindow. Sounds complicated, but isn't:

```
infowindowObject.setContent(document.getElementById('formDiv'));
```

This will not have any effect to the DOM, but it will:

1. set the content-property of the infoWindow to the current contents
2. fire the content_changed-event, so the infoWindow should be resized.

Comment: Thanks for the response; I reset the content of the infoWindow after the validate plugin finished, but the infowindow still doesn't re-size. I'm getting the following error in the console:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'setContent' of undefined
But the infoWindow variable is global.

Comment: When I follow your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rhewitt/gqa6k/1/ there is a global markerWindow-variable, but this variable will not contain the infoWindow, because you create markerWindow inside placeMarker() by using the var-keyword, what creates a new markerWindow-variable inside the function which is not global. Remove the var-keyword.

Comment: I didn't realize I re-declared that variable thanks -- error rectified.  The infowindow is now partially re-sizing! I'm going to play with the CSS values and see if that takes care of it.